# WPF's command firing twice on fast doubleclick

Tags: wpf

From a production application, we notice that our WPF buttons fire the ICommand.Execute method twice on fast double click.

Now, on every Command, the application is covered with a full-screen spinner animation, preventing any further interaction with the application.

[This github](https://github.com/koenj/WpfDoubleClick) repo contains a minimalistic repro of the issue. Note that:

- when the Button's Command fires, the "IsBusy" flag is set to true
- as a consequence, the BusyIndicator overlay will be shown
- as a consequence, the Button cannot be pressed again until after 300ms

However, especially on slow computers, when fast double-clicking (really fast, like gaming fast that is), it is possible to fire the command twice without the BusyIndicator blocking the second call (this can be seen if the output shows 2 'click' lines right after one another).

This is unexpected behavior to me, as the IsBusy flag is set to true right away on the UI thread.
How come a second click is able to pass through?
I would expect the IsBusy Binding to show the overlay on the UI thread, blocking any further interaction?

The github sample also contains 2 workarounds:

1. using the ICommand.CanExecute to block the Execute handler
2. using the PreviewMouseDown to prevent double clicks

I'm trying to understand what the issue is.
What work-around would you prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Diagnosis

This is only my guess and not a solid and confirmed info, but it seems that when you click the mouse button, the hit-testing is done immediately, but all the mouse related events are only scheduled to be raised (using the `Dispatcher` I presume). The important thing is that the control that is clicked is determined at the time the click occurred, and not after the previous click has been completely handled (including all UI changes that potentially follow).

So in your case, even if the first click results in showing the `BusyIndicator` covering (and thus blocking) the `Button`, if you manage to click for the second time before the `BusyIndicator` is actually shown (and that does not happen immediately), the click event on the `Button` will be scheduled to be raised (which will happen after the `BusyIndicator` is shown), causing the command to be executed again even though at that point the `BusyIndicator` will possibly be blocking the `Button`.

## Solution

If your goal is to prevent command execution while the previous one is still executing the obvious choice is to make the `Command.CanExecute` result depend on the state of the `IsBusy` flag. Moreover, I wouldn't even call it a *workaround*, but a **proper design**.

What you're facing here is a clear-cut example of why you shouldn't make your business logic rely on UI. Firstly, because rendering strongly depends on the machine's processing power, and secondly because covering a button with another control by far does not guarantee the button cannot be "clicked" (using for example [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) framework).